# ActiveMQ client: share connection between sessions?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm using the ActiveMQ client library to connect my server application to ActiveMQ. Several different consumers and producers run in individual threads. How should the relationship between [`ActiveMQConnectionFactory`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.13.3/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.html), [`ActiveMQConnection`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.13.3/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnection.html) and [`ActiveMQSession`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.13.3/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSession.html) be?

- one connection factory per JVM
- one connection to the broker per JVM ***or*** n connections, one per consumer
- n sessions, one per consumer (the Javadoc seems to strongly suggest this)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [activemq connection pooling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218990/activemq-connection-pooling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [How do I use JMS efficiently?](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-jms-efficiently.html).

You should also think about using connection pooling.